# Django - The current path did not match any of url pattern

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

Getting Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/picture/7/pic/31/delete/None

instead of  http://127.0.0.1:8000/picture/7/pic/31/delete/

Why it's adding **/None** at the end?

```
#html
action="{% url 'picture:item-delete' pic.album_id pic.pk %}"

#views.py

class ItemDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Pic

    def get_success_url(self):
        reverse_lazy('picture:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.album_id})

#urls.py

urlpatterns = [

# /picture/<album_id>/pic/<pic_id>/delete/
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/pic/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.ItemDelete.as_view(), name='item-delete'),

]
```

Though, it deleted the model(pic).

Comment: You forgot the `return`, so the method implicitly returns `None`. It should be `return reverse_lazy(...)`.

Comment: You can use regular `reverse` there because it’s in a method, you don’t need `reverse_lazy`.

Comment: I don't even notice that 'return' is missing.